# Why is not working in AVD?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

1. Example aplication works fine on real device (tested on: Nexsus One, Galaxy S)
2. Example uses pre-compiled open-cv lib-s, exactly javacv
3. On android virtual device AVD, same example is not working it crashes on pre-loading external library (AVD hardware added for camera and network support, 1024RAM, max VM heap size 64MB). 
   Exact line where it stops is: 
   com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(opencv_objdetect.class);
   in short: Loader.load(opencv_objdetect.class);
4. LogCat (lot of reports)

   - Process terminated by signal (4)
   - Process has ... died.

Is there any additional setting in AVD to make this simple app work or I`m I missing something?

Comment: Add your answer below and accept it so that the question get marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case .so files were compiled for ARMv7 that is not supported in emulator, also some Android devices don't have FPU - effect is the same.

So if you are developing 3rd party libraries please provide both version (recompile). It is important that it works in emulator (teaching etc...).

Answer (score 0):

check the Api level of Avd i.e set Api level 8, as nexus one having api level 8

Comment: Tried! Main problem was (is) that .so file is compiled for ARMv7 and emulator doesn't support it. Thanks for idea anyway.